# Why doesn't "replace" command work as expected in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, replace

I have created the following pandas dataframe:

```
ds = {"col1":["Mr Stuart (Acting)", "Mr Smith", "John Ross (Acting)"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=ds)
```

Which looks like this:

```
print(df)
                 col1
0  Mr Stuard (Acting)
1            Mr Smith
2  John Ross (Acting)
```

I want to `replace` `" (Acting)"` (in `col1`) with nothing.

So I have written this piece of code:

```
df = df.replace(to_replace=" (Acting)",value="",)
```

But the " (Acting)" bit is still present in the resulting dataframe:

```
print(df)
                 col1
0  Mr Stuard (Acting)
1            Mr Smith
2  John Ross (Acting)
```

Can someone tell me why the `replace` command is not working? And how can I replace " (Acting)" with nothing?

Comment: `df.replace(to_replace=r"\s*\(Acting\)",value="",)`